# mat-dialog tiene un borde en la parte derecha ¿cómo lo quito?

Tags: angular

Quiero redondear mas las esquinas de un mat-dialog, esto lo hago sin problema pero en la parte derecha del dialogo hay un borde blanco, ¿[image: IMAGEN DEL DIALOGO]como lo quito?

Answer (score 0):

Utilicé un estilo para el scroll del mat-dialog, la mejor solución es brindarle un alto al mat-container y colocarle el estilo del scroll a este y al mat-dialog aplicarle el estilo de manera que no se muestre el scroll.